# How to extract all of the names, down to the most deeply nested sublist, of an R list?

Tags: r, list

How would I extract all of the names, digging down to the most deeply nested sublist names, from an R list, as shown in the below image? Code for replicating this example list is presented at the bottom of this post and is representative of a larger, dynamic list I am working with. The list object I am trying to extract the nested sublist names from is called `list_tmp` in the below code. If possible, I would rather do this in base R in order to avoid "package bloat", or one of the super-standard packages like dplyr or tidyverse if base R is onerous.

[image]

Code to generate this example list:

```
# Create the matrix for columns Col_A and Col_B
mat_tmp <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
colnames(mat_tmp) <- c("Col_A","Col_B")

# Build list
list_tmp1 <- list(
  Top = list(
    Middle_One = list(
      A = mat_tmp,
      B = mat_tmp,
      Total = mat_tmp
    ),
    Middle_Two = list(
      A = mat_tmp,
      Total = mat_tmp
    )
  )
)

list_tmp2 <- list(
  Top = list(
    Total = mat_tmp
  )
)

list_tmp3 <- list(
  Top = list(
    Other = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
  )
)

list_tmp <- c(list_tmp1,list_tmp2, list_tmp3)
```

Comment: For clarity, one of the bottom-most names is `"A"`, not `"Top$Middle_One$A"`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So, I'm looking for the complete "chain" of names, all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the names you want, you can use a recursive function

```
node_names <- function(x, prefix="") {
  if (is.list(x)) {
    unname(unlist(mapply(node_names, x, paste0(prefix, "$", names(x)))))
  } else {
    prefix
  }
}
node_names(list_tmp)
# [1] "$Top$Middle_One$A"     "$Top$Middle_One$B"     "$Top$Middle_One$Total" "$Top$Middle_Two$A"    
# [5] "$Top$Middle_Two$Total" "$Top$Total"            "$Top$Other"
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
full_names <- list()
get_names <- function(x, ancestors = character(0)) {
  if (!is.list(x)) {
    full_names <<- c(full_names, paste(ancestors, collapse = "$"))
  } else {
    for (i in seq_along(x)) get_names(x[[i]], ancestors = c(ancestors, names(x)[i]))
  }
}
get_names(list_tmp)
unlist(full_names)

# [1] "Top$Middle_One$A"     "Top$Middle_One$B"     "Top$Middle_One$Total" "Top$Middle_Two$A"     "Top$Middle_Two$Total"
# [6] "Top$Total"            "Top$Other"
```